# Laptop Overheating Yoga 9i Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: overheating, temperature

I'm currently dual booting Ubuntu on my laptop for work purposes. One thing that I have noticed is that the laptop is running extremely hot doing relatively low intensity work. I use a flashcard app called Anki which seems to be the main driver of the heat, however running it similarly on Windows doesn't cause nearly the same issues. Frequently hitting 95 degrees on the CPU +. Is there anyway to tell what is causing the issues?

[CPU Temps & Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuCGW.png)

Comment: Which kernel version are you running? `uname -a` will show it.

Comment: Hello! This is what comes up.  5.13.0-40-generic #45~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP